# SQL Query aggregate may not appear in WHERE clause (AVG)

Tags: sql

Hi I can't find a solution how to fix this problem.

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
from [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p
where p.UnitPrice > AVG(p.UnitPrice)
group by p.UnitPrice
```

Should be like this : AVG is 28.3 so UnitPrice higher than 28.3

```
ProductName                        UnitPrice
Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears     30,00
Northwoods Cranberry Sauce          40,00
Mishi Kobe Niku                     97,00
Ikura                               31,00
Queso Manchego La Pastora           38,00
Alice Mutton                        39,00
```

Having also don't work

```
select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
from [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p
group by p.UnitPrice
having p.UnitPrice > AVG(p.UnitPrice)
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result  - all as formatted text, not images.  ([mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery instead:

```
select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
from [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p
where p.UnitPrice > (select avg(p2.UnitPrice)
                     from [DESKTOP-509LB9L\MSSQLSERVER01].northwind.dbo.products p2
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you I was fighting with it 1 hour, I tried using subquery but didn't categorise the  ``` select avg(p2.UnitPrice)....... but as select avg(p.UnitPrice) ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subquery to compute average before compare it to unit price

```
select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice
from northwind.dbo.products p
where p.UnitPrice>
(
    select AVG(p2.UnitPrice)
    from northwind.dbo.products p2
    group by p2.ProductName
    having p2.ProductName = p.ProductName
)
```

You should ensure your product name is unique or use the product key instead of name